# Pass Input parameter to the GET Rest API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I have a REST endpoint to which I need to pass the input parameter like below within the quotes

```
/api/rooms?filter=name='A1'
```

If I donot pass the parameter with quotes it will error. So within my code how can I call the end point with the input parameter with in single quotes and get the response. Below is what I tried  but not sure it is the correct way

```
public async Task<string> GetRoomID(string roomName)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_iconfiguration.GetSection("RoomMovement").GetSection("BaseAddress").Value);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/rooms?filter=name=" + roomName).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync($"api/rooms?filter=name='{roomName}'").ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? You can just add the 's to your string individually!

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/rooms?filter=name=" + "'" + roomName + "'").ConfigureAwait(false);
```